# Method 'create' not found in class Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm, laravel-5.3

I'm using Laravel 5.3, in PhpStorm there is error under the method 'create' and many other methods. I tried all the ide_helpers but nothing resolved it

[image]

is there anyway to resolve this and the autocomplete?

Comment: Use this: php artisan ide-helper:models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer the problem was with the use lines :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
```

first line should be replaced with:

```
use Schema;
```

Comment: I did as you recommended anb phpStorm said that Schema is never user. I deleted the line and it works fine.

Comment: I can confirm that if you remove the line "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema" (and don't add the other) it will work in PHPStorm.

Comment: None of the above suggestions work. If you remove or change the first line PhpStorm says (predictably) "Undefined class Schema".