# Class 'Illuminate\Support\facades\Schema' not found

Tags: laravel-5

I am working with Laravel5.4. When I use socialite package to login with Facebook, I need to add this line of

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

to boot function of `AppServiceProvider` class in order to create default password for new user.

Beside that I have to add using statement at top of `AppServiceProvider` class like this

```
use Illuminate\Support\facades\Schema;
```

Everything is working well on my localhost but when I upload all code to my share hosting, I get this error

> Class 'Illuminate\Support\facades\Schema' not found.

Can anyone help me on this. I am highly appreciated your help!

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked whether a capital `f` in front of `facades` solves the problem?

Answer (score 4):

OMG I follow the marked answer of question below and  replace the using statement with

```
use Schema;
```

and the error gone. But I still don't know why it works well on local and only cause error on server.

[Method 'create' not found in class Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964026/method-create-not-found-in-class-illuminate-support-facades-schema)

Answer (score 3):

Fix Capitalize Error and replace:

```
use Illuminate\Support\facades\Schema;
```

with

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

The reason it might work on local and not work on server is that probably you're using windows locally, and Linux hosting account which is case-sensitive regarding the paths and filenames

Comment: please add tags to put it in proper channel

Answer (score 2):

*In my case, I use capital letter its work.*

```
use Illuminate\Support\facades\Schema;
```

**replace with this**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error when i hosted website .

Class 'Illuminate\Support\facades\Schema' not found.

then i just replaced use Illuminate\Support\facades\schema; with use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to change 
use Illuminate\Support\facades\Schema;

to

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

Facades needs to capital F

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
use Illuminate\Support\facades\Schema;
```

With this:

```
use Schema;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. I don't think that `Schema` does not use any namespace, just have a look at https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Facades/Schema.php

Comment: it is already set in the Config\app alias section

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my `Laravel 8.40` and `PHP 7.4`.

So for solving the problem I changed the `facades` to capital `Facades` in my `AppServiceProvider.php` file at this path `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` on line 6:

```
use Illuminate\Support\facades\Schema;
```

To

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just closed Visual Studio Code, and all the terminals, then ran the server again. It worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score -1):

You must set the .env file
This setting

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ilk
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

n

```
amespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
//hata almamak ıcın
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;


class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
      Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
     }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should adding an `.env` file solve the given error message?