# Laravel: Method 'defaultStringLength' not found in \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using PHPStorm and I'm learning Laravel.

For "key too long" error I'm following the fix here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#creating-indexes

But, PHPStorm complaints for

`Method 'defaultStringLength' not found in \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema`

Why and how can I Solve? This is my `AppServiceProvider.php` file

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        /**
         * Fix for key too long.
         * @see https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#creating-indexes
         */
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem once and followed the answer from the following link to solve my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44859379/4437710

Basically, replace `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;` with `use Schema;` I don't know the reason for this strange behavior. I'm not sure if it will work on your case too. But you can give it a try.

**Another trick taken from the internet (Not tested by me):**
For Laravel 5.4, use `\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder::defaultStringLength(191);` for correct function reference path instead